# Uber Cadence Workflow Version Change Compatibility

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I understand that I cannot make backward incompatible changes to Workflows per:
[How to make changes or fixes to Uber Cadence Workflow without breaking determinism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840408/how-to-make-changes-or-fixes-to-uber-cadence-workflow-without-breaking-determini)

However I am not sure what "backward incompatible" means here.  Can I simply not deploy new code without using getVersion, period?  Or as long as the history tracking that is used for restoration is compatible between the 2 versions then I can update without getVersion?  Or I can update without getVersion under some under conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Generally anything that can change the way the history is generated is considered backwards incompatible. The following changes are backwards compatible:

- Any activity implementation.
- Duration passed to sleep and timer creation function.
- Changing arguments to activities.
- Changing activity options and retry policies.
- Changing values of variables that don't affect the workflow execution path. For example if some variable accumulates some data and this data is only used in a query.

We recommend saving a few histories and then replaying them as part of unit tests to find out about non compatible changes earlier.